# draw a circle of rectangles in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried this code to draw a circle of rectangle

```
incNumberDefault=0;
for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
   incNumberDefault = incNumberDefault +5;


   UIView *myView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(incNumberDefault, 100, 3, 15)];
   myView.center = CGPointMake(130,130);
   myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(incNumberDefault));
   myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
   [self.speedDisplay addSubview:myView];
}
```

the outputs seems  close circle where as i need transparent or space in middle of circle.

Answer (score 2):

You can set UIView cornerRadius to half of the UIView width or height like,

`myView.layer.cornerRadius=myview.frame.size.width / 2;` or

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius=myview.frame.size.height / 2
```

For that you have to give same width and height to your UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// initialize the view with same height and width for perfect circle.
   UIView *myView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 15, 15)];

// round the corner of view with required radius. 
    myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/2; // height can also be used 

// circle with space in middle.
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    myView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
   [self.speedDisplay addSubview:myView];
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to develop a dashed circle in certain certain distance.

Comment: Can you show the image of dashed circle you want to draw ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but i want to develop a dashed circle in certain distance and i have tired this code :

```
incNumberDefault=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumber; i++) {
     UIView *myView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100+60 * sin(incNumberDefault), 100+60*cos(incNumberDefault), 3, 15)];
     //myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(incNumberDefault));
     myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
     [self.speedDisplay addSubview:myView];
      incNumberDefault = incNumberDefault +9;

   }
```

but it generate random rectangle in a circle.
I want it in sequence.

Thank you.